# Matching a longest word using Regex only

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to match longest word of given string using regex: 
for example given string

- S = "hello night axe axbxbxx prom  etc..."
- character set 1 = [abcdexy]
- character set 2 = [mnrpo]

I need to get only one word that match 2 constriants, all the word should contain characters from one set only and the chosen word should be the longest, I tried to solve this using php regex such as:

```
preg_match("/\b[abcdexy]+/",$s, $match1);
preg_match("/\b[mnrpo]+/",$s, $match2);
if(strlen($match1[0]) > strlen($match2[0]))
{
  //output match1[0];
}
else
{
 //output match2[0]
}
```

The expected output should be axbxbxx since it contain only characters from set 1 and it is the longest between words that belong to one of the two sets.

My question is, can I make this work using only regex without need for strlen() testing?

Comment: What's the expected output for the sample string your provided? It's not clear what you're trying to do given then regular expressions don't actually match a single word in your string.

Comment: You could first use the regex to capture the strings you want and later check the length of each group

Comment: I edited the question to add expected output.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza This exactly what I do, but I need to be implemented in pure regex without any other functions

Comment: split the string by space and check result (array) for longest word, Regex not for this task

Comment: @DmitriGudkov: Re-read the question the words must contain only letters in character class.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do with regex alone. You have to use `strlen()`.

Comment: @ParcRoi, you can't... regex doesn't do logic, just pattern matching

Comment: But \b already return the longest match for one class, so why we can't do it globally for all classes? anyway thank you guys. If no one give a solution I'll have to go with strlen() solution.

Comment: `\b` doesn't return the longest match, it's a word boundary that make sure we don't have a word character before.

Comment: @Toto , you are right using \b made a behavior where preg_match was returning the longest word so I thought this what \b do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a single regex expression that uses a pipe to match both character ranges, then sort the matched values by descending length and access the first element's value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/fm9aB))

```
$string='hello proxy night pom-pom-mop axe prom etc decayed';
if (preg_match_all('~\b(?:[a-exy]+|[m-pr]+)\b~', $string, $out)) {
    usort($out[0], function($a, $b) {return strlen($b) - strlen($a);});  // or spaceship operator if you like
    echo $out[0][0];
} else {
    echo "no matches";
}
```

Output:

```
decayed
```

The above method is not "tie-aware" so if you have two values or more values that share the highest length, you will only get one value in the output.  I think you need to build in some additional logic to handle these fringe cases like:

- Output all highest length values or
- Set a secondary criteria to break ties on length

I'll not bother coding up these solution extensions since I prefer not to go down rabbit holes.